# cursor does not show date value in mysql procedure

Tags: mysql, cursor

```
DECLARE no_more_rows BOOLEAN;
DECLARE loop_cntr INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE num_rows INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE nrl_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE tap_pro_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE agr_date Date;
DECLARE tap_proposed_start_date Date;
DECLARE tap_proposed_end_date Date;
DECLARE tap_rent_type varchar(20);
DECLARE tap_creation_ts TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE tap_previous_date TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE tap_usr_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE tap_com_id INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE lease_fire_date TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE increment_fire_date TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE increment_next_fire_date TIMESTAMP;

DEClARE lease_cursor CURSOR FOR 
select
    ta.TAP_PROPERTY_ID,
    ta.TAP_PROPOSED_START_DATE,
    ta.TAP_PROPOSED_END_DATE,
    ta.TAP_RENT_TYPE,
    ad.AGR_CREATION_TS,
    ad.AGR_CREATED_BY,
    apd.APP_COM_ID
FROM agreement_details ad,tenancy_applications ta,application_details apd 
WHERE ad.AGR_APP_ID=ta.TAP_APP_ID AND apd.APP_ID=ta.TAP_APP_ID;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
SET no_more_rows = TRUE;
open lease_cursor;
select FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows;

get_lease:Loop
    FETCH lease_cursor INTO 
        tap_pro_id,
        tap_proposed_start_date,
        tap_proposed_end_date,
        tap_rent_type,
        tap_creation_ts,
        tap_usr_id,
        tap_com_id;
```

in above code i am able to get data into cursor but tap_proposed_start_date,tap_proposed_end_date always '0000-00-00'

Comment: What value do you expect there to be?

Comment: @Nakul . . . What is the data type of `ta.TAP_PROPOSED_START_DATE`?  What does the data look like?

Comment: @GordonLinoff it is of 'Date' type

Comment: @AmazingDreams i am expecting date which come from database

Comment: @GordonLinoff its format is yyyy-mm-dd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i add DATE_FORMAT statement in select as

```
DEClARE lease_cursor CURSOR FOR select ta.TAP_PROPERTY_ID,**DATE_FORMAT(ta.TAP_PROPOSED_START_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d'),DATE_FORMAT   (ta.TAP_PROPOSED_END_DATE,'%Y-%m-%d')**,ta.TAP_RENT_TYPE,
ad.AGR_CREATION_TS,ad.AGR_CREATED_BY,apd.APP_COM_ID
from agreement_details ad,tenancy_applications ta,application_details apd where  ad.AGR_APP_ID=ta.TAP_APP_ID and apd.APP_ID=ta.TAP_APP_ID;
```